# What is the right syntax of IF statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, syntax, if-statement

I have a small and simple MySQL code. But whenever I run it, I get error #1064.  Can you tell me what is my mistake here?

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_states) > 0) THEN
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM tbl_cities;
    END
END IF
```

I also used some other conditions like the below one, but again I got an error.

```
IF (1=1) THEN
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM tbl_cities;
    END
END IF
```

What I actually want to do is something like this:

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_states) > 0) THEN
    BEGIN
        UPDATE ...
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT ...
    END
END IF
```

Comment: Are you writing a query or a procedure ? It's really not the same thing.

Comment: What is your actual goal here? Are you actually wanting to perform an INSERT on a different table if the tbl_states table contains no records where the id field has a non-null value? Because that's what your code is implying. Or, taking a logical leap, are you actually trying to update a row with a specified id if it exists and insert it otherwise?

Comment: Then I'm afraid it gets really complicated and we'll need more information about your tables. But you should also consider a procedure for this kind of job and look at manurajhada's answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is a procedure you're writing you should try:

```
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_states) > 0) THEN
        SELECT * FROM tbl_cities;
    END IF
END
```

If it is a query, `BEGIN` and `END` have nothing to do here.

**Edit**

Well, there is not really more to say, `IF ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_states) > 0) THEN SELECT * FROM tbl_cities; END IF` is simply not respecting the basic MySQL [SELECT statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

You should start with `SELECT`... etc...

Comment: I still get error with this one in my query.
`IF ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_states) > 0) THEN SELECT * FROM tbl_cities; END IF`

Comment: Olivier do you mean () are extra? I have to remove them before and after first `select` statement?

Comment: may you help me please? Unfortunately none of different suggestions here could not help me. I want to insert a new row, if a select statement returns `count=0`, and update a row if it returns `count>0`. I hope I could show my need to you.

Comment: I know this is old, but for the benefit of future readers, if you want this to be automatic on some update/insert/delete then you want a trigger; if you want to be able to call this action at any time, you need a routine (stored procedure). You cannot do this in a single (or even multiple) simple queries.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_cities WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_states)
```

Comment: xdazz, I want to know what is wrong in my code? It's very strange for me

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_cities WHERE (SELECT count(1) FROM tbl_states)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *  FROM test2 where (select count(*) from test) > 0;
```

Here you need to use [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) to create conditional execution..
Try this..

```
CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_states) > 0) THEN
    BEGIN
        UPDATE ...
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT ...
    END
END
```

Comment: I could not do it with CASE. This was my code: `CASE
 WHEN (1<2) THEN
  SELECT * FROM tbl_states;
 WHEN (1>2) THEN
  SELECT * FROM tbl_cities;
END CASE` But I got error for this too.

Comment: munurajhada, I'd like to know why there are these problems while working with MySQL. I used a simple condition `1<2` in my code, but it did not work at all. This is more important for me to know what's the matter?

Comment: As I told you, you *just can't* write what you did in a query. `BEGIN`, `END`, etc are only used in procedures.

Comment: no u can't, its simple condition for you only !! 
as an alternate user `count(tbl_states)` in you server code and execute the update/insert query acc to that.