# Select from statement 2 if no results from table1

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to do something with MySQL that I'm not sure is possible or worth doing in one query.

I have columns 1, 2, 3 from Table A I'm interested in.

```
SELECT 1, 2, 3
FROM A
WHERE 1 = somevalue
```

OR columns 4, 5, 6 from Table B if the above does not appear.

```
SELECT 4, 5, 6
FROM B
WHERE 4 = some value
```

I looked into the case statement, but I'm not quite sure the appropriate syntax to find a value in another table if another doesn't exist in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 1,2,3, 'A' AS source
    FROM A
    WHERE 1 = somevalue

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 4,5,6, 'B'
    FROM B
    WHERE 4 = somevalue
) AS subs
ORDER BY source ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Get both sets of records from both tables, and sort by the derived "source" field. If there's no matching records in the `A` table, then that subquery will simply return no rows, and you'll get only the `B` records.

If both tables have matching records, then since you're sorting by the name of the source table (`A` or `B`), then the limit will ensure that only the first row from the `A` table comes through.

Comment: This will query the 2nd table even if the first does contain results though

Comment: well, there's no provision in sql to "select from this and then select from that if the first one didn't return anything"

Comment: From an efficiency standpoint, would it make more sense to execute the query to table A, check the results, and if there are none, then and only then query table B?

Comment: That's what I would've done but you did say one query. Check out the `FOUND_ROWS()` function

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11427457/781965) describing the `IF` statement syntax.

I'm a SQL Server guy so I might get this wrong but something like this should do you:

```
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT BLAH FROM A) = BLAH) THEN
        SELECT BLAH FROM A;
    ELSEIF ((select BLAH from B) = BLAH) THEN 
        SELECT BLAH FROM B;
    END IF
END
```

Preumably you'd want to do something like `SELECT count(*) FROM A WHERE X` in your `IF` statement.

Comment: Just noticed the "one query" bit - this isn't one query but it is how I would do it. Otherwise I guess you could do something with sub-selects, but I very much doubt it would actually improve performance.